# Azure cost analysis and invoices - exchange rates

Tags: azure, currency, cost-management, azure-billing-api, azure-billing

when I use the Consumption usage details API I am getting usage cost details day wise. I saw that azure uses USD for billing and show invoices in the customer's local currency [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/microsoft-customer-agreement/microsoft-customer-agreement-faq#what-exchange-rate-will-be-used-and-how-does-it-work-with-my-bill) so that How exchange rates are selected for this case (whether previous day rate or at the time rate or previous month rate) and which exchange rate will be used for the invoice.

During invoice, whether the same exchange rate will be applied to all daily split up bills or exchange rates are chosen as per usage date.

[referred link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/microsoft-customer-agreement/microsoft-customer-agreement-faq#what-exchange-rate-will-be-used-and-how-does-it-work-with-my-bill)

Comment: From the link you mentioned - `We use Thomson Reuters benchmark rates that are captured at the end of the previous month and go into effect on the first day of the next calendar month. This rate applies to all transactions during the upcoming month.`

Comment: yes but in same content, there is an example  : 

**For example, the exchange rate for January transactions is first captured in the final days of December. This rate will be applied to all Azure purchases made in January and all Azure consumption in January. The January exchange rate and local currency billed amount will appear in the January invoice, which is available at the beginning of February.**

This makes a confusion they told that invoice for January month contains exchange rate of January but actually it should take December month exchange rate as per previous statement.

Comment: Yeah. The way I inferred this is that any purchases you make in January, you pay the same rate which is based on the exchange rate at the end of December. The rate remains same throughout January.

Comment: `This makes a confusion they told that invoice for January month contains exchange rate of January but actually it should take December month exchange rate as per previous statement.` - I believe this is just for your reference only that for February what rate are they going to use.

Comment: BTW, you should raise a billing support request with Azure and ask them this question.

Comment: yes, thank you,  I raised a support request